# bindmodel vs createmodel asp mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, model-binding, defaultmodelbinder, modelbinder

I am developping my first application in Asp. I am using the environment Asp.NET MVC 3. 
I have a controller Action that has a single parameter. The type of this parameter is a complex object.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(ComplexObj obj) {
    //TODO: using obj
}
```

I am using a ModelBinder class. But I am not sure if I should override the **BindModel** function or the **CreateModel** one.

What's the difference beween those two functions and when they are used exactely by the rooter.

Thanks !

Comment: Why you want to go for a custom model binder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What's the difference beween those two functions and when they are
>   used exactely by the rooter.

`BindModel` is the main method that does all the work in the model binding process and on the way it calls the `CreateModel` method to provide an instance of the model based on the passed type. The `CreateModel` method checks the model type whether it is a `dictionary` or `list` or a simple model and finally returns an instance by calling,

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeToCreate);
```

Usually you have to go for overriding the `BindModel` method and unless you say your requirement it's diffcult to say which one to override. If all you care about is to only override the way the model instance is created then you have to go for `CreateModel`.

Comment: Think you for your answer. I tryed to go inside the method BindModel with "F11". That was not possible since I don't have the implementation. You can understand that I am a begginer in C# :-/ How can I discover by my self such helpfull informations (that CreateModel is called by BindModel) ?